# How to pass server urls to Watir Ruby unit tests run by Rake under Thoughtworks Cruise

Tags: rake, watir, cruisecontrol

I'm currently building a suite of Watir tests for my .net web application.

I have wired the watir tests into the Thoughtworks Cruise continuous build using Rake.

What is the best way to pass a number of server urls to the watir tests so I can run the tests against a number of different environments? e.g. build, test, uat etc.

Cheers!

Comment: If you want more answers, post the question at http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I store server URLs simply in a variable. If there are more than one, [array](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) could be useful. You can store them in a file ([YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) format is popular). What is the problem you are trying to solve? URLs are changing a lot?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help.. So the problem is I want to use the same 12 test scripts against 3 different environments - buid, test, uat.  I want the test scripts to stay the same and just the configuration of the cruise/rake build task to change.  A yaml file sounds like a good option, will take a look.  Thanks!